# how to move a window through a python application?

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python. I'm wondering if there's a way to move a window. Like in turtle, you can move it 'this' many squares to the right or whatever. I was wondering if there was a way to do that with a window instead?

Comment: what window are you talking about? ... what OS?

Comment: How to move a tkinter window as you can in turtle.

Comment: tkinter allows you to set the window size and position on a desktop ... are you not able to position a window?